# Vapor 4 Fluent ORM cannot get Sort to work

Tags: fluent, vapor

I cannot for the life of me get this sort to work in Vapor 4, and cannot find more clarification in the documentation:

I have a function as follows:

```
 func getTopIdeas(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Idea]> {
        // Get the civicConcernID from the request
        guard let civicConcernID = req.parameters.get("civicConcernID", as: UUID.self) else {
            throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "Missing civicConcernID parameter.")
        }

        // Set the number of top ideas to retrieve (X)
        let numberOfTopIdeas = 10

        // Query the ideas
        return Idea.query(on: req.db)
            .with(\.$ideaMeritScoreMetric) // Eager load the ideaMeritScoreMetric
            .filter(\.$civicConcern.$id == civicConcernID)
            .sort(\.$ideaMeritScoreMetric.meritScore, .descending)
            .range(..<numberOfTopIdeas) // Limit the results to the top X ideas
            .all()
            
    }
```

The query works find without the sort, but not matter what path I put in I get errors.

The above provides the following error:

`Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type`

If I change to:
`.sort(\Idea.$ideaMeritScoreMetric.meritScore, .descending)`

Get This Error:
`Value of type 'OptionalChildProperty<Idea, IdeaMeritScoreMetric>' has no member 'meritScore'`

Comment: Hi, did my answer solve your problem? Feedback helps other users and me know how useful it is. Please consider accepting and upvoting if it did or let me know if not.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't checked in a while. But yes this is the solution that works.

For more context, I essentially learned that in order to do any filtering, sorting, etc, a join is required if one intends to sort/filter on the joined object... Trying to filter on an eagerloaded object seems to fail everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to get sorting working like this. I don't think it is possible. Doing an explicit join works. Try:

```swift
Idea.query(on: req.db)
    .with(\.$ideaMeritScoreMetric)
    .join(IdeaMeritScoreMetric.self, on: \User.$ideaMeritScoreMetric.$id == \IdeaMeritScoreMetric.$id)
    .sort(IdeaMeritScoreMetric.self, \.$meritScore, .descending)
```

The eager load is still useful because you can use it to access the joined results more easily than via the join, although there is presumably a performance penalty.